# Как оставить клавиатуру видимой после нажатия на ОК(Done) в ней для EditText android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, клавиатура

Есть EditText в приложении на android.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_game_word"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true" > 

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Когда я нажимаю на ОК(Done), в показываемой клавиатуре, она скрывается, но я наоборот хочу чтобы клавиатура оставалось видимой. Я пробовал добавить InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, чтобы после каждого нажатия на ОК она сразу же показывалась, но это не работает.

```
editTextWord.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
            someCode();
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                    getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }    
        return false;
    }
});
```

Также пробовал ставить в активити

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

но результат тот же. Как можно сделать это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        EditText editDone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDone);
        editDone.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d("...", "кнопка нажата и клава видна");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Столько бился, а оказывается всё так просто, всего лишь false на true исправить. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Пожалуйста, ну зато вы теперь больше знаете про keybord в android, пока искали решение.